# Correct syntax for multiple loops with list integers in Python

Tags: python, list, iteration

I'm working on a loop that is basically the following

```
MyList = ['cttgaaat',attcggat',gtatcaag'...] 

for value in text_file:
     print(key_nucleotide_position)
```

key_nucleotide_position is a given number from a text file, which would
return something like this

```
In [1]: 1
        3
        5
        7
        ...
```

I'm trying a for loop that looks something like this

```
for value in MyList: 
     print(value[key_nucleotide_position])
     print('\n')
```

However, instead of printing what I want, which would be

```
t
t
t

g
c
t

a
g
a

t
t
g
```

I'm getting only this

```
t

t

g
```

I've managed to get it to work when I put a for loop within another for loop, but that just gives me a super long sequence of nucleotides (497 lines) in this format

```
a
t
t
g
g
c
g
...
```

which I know how to analyze, but not how to split it in the manner I want it to be split, which would be every 91 nucleotides - even then, the return value doesn't exactly make sense for the number of nucleotides I should get.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please correct the syntax in the first block of code snippet. and what is `information_file`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please ask your question in a proper and nicely formatted way.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to help is with full details. I will infer this is school related and try to point you in the right direction. It is most helpful to post reproducible examples so that someone can easily recreate the setup and troubleshoot. Try using things like [gists](https://gist.github.com/) or [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) if you have long files.

From your description, I think you have:

- a list of small sequences
- a text file of numbers, one per line

I think you want to take your list of `n` sequences, iterate through the integers in your file of `key_nucleotide_position` integers, and extract the `ith` element of `MyList`?

Let's just walk through what you're doing, first seeing how you iterate through `MyList`:

```
MyList = ['cttgaaat', 'attcggat', 'gtatcaag']
for value in MyList: 
     print(value)

cttgaaat
attcggat
gtatcaag
```

Assuming a number (say, `3`) is stored in the variable `key_nucleotide_position`, you're doing this with each loop:

```
MyList = ['cttgaaat', 'attcggat', 'gtatcaag']
for value in MyList:
     print(value[3])
```

Using the first value in `MyList`, let's see what that does:

```
'cttgaaat'[3]
g
```

You're extracting the `ith` character from the string according to the integer slice.

It's not exactly clear from the question, but I'm guessing you might want to reverse this and get the `ith` item from the *list*, not the `ith` character in the string.

i.e. consider:

```
MyList[1]

'attcggat'
```

Now, get your `for` loop to cycle through such that `MyList[foo]` changes `foo` to what you want on each loop.